# How to get the header row thats is (A or B or C) by passing the column name

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I'm using exceljs library and I have Workbook with two sheets (**masterdata**  and **sheetB**)
In master_data sheet first column status is having values [1 2 3 4 5] and I want to create dropdown in sheetB using masterdata's **status** column values. Is there a way read column names header value **(A)** ? In this case the master_dat sheet **status** column header value that is **A**. so that I pass that **A** below in formulae field.

```
worksheet.getCell('A1').dataValidation = {
  type: 'list',
  allowBlank: true,
  formulae: ['$A$1:$A$5']
};
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the worksheet name:

```
worksheet.getCell('A1').dataValidation = {
    type: 'list',
    allowBlank: true,
    formulae: ['masterdata!$A$1:$A$5']
};
```